# How to fix java (in javafx) out-of-control memory consumtion besides Xmx, MaxPermSize?

Tags: java, memory-usage, graphical-user-interface

-Xmx, -XX:MaxPermSize not helping, OS is Ubuntu 16.10

First I ran my javafx experiment loading some pics and showing them in cycle using canvas node. Now I run javafx demo apps (different) ver. jdk1.8.0_112 and jdk1.8.0_111 on corresponding jvm's. The results are same: after a few minutes everything becomes glitchy and unresponsive. If I use `ulimit -Sv`, the program crashes soon, or doesn't start, due to insufficient memory.

Here are what I see just after the program start and in less than 2 minutes of it performing animation:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1r4f.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtmUa.png)

The strangeness is that when I run this at work (system complete format-reinstall doesn't help), memory grows indefinitely, while at home this same program can slow down, but works and takes less than 1G of memory.
At home I use older PC with Intel i7 processor and Radeon discrete graphics, at work newer Intel i7  and built-in graphics. OS is the same. Have no clue what else could matter.

Comment: First you need to specify how much free memory you have on your system. What OS are you running. How much RAM you have on your machine. What are the settings for Java memory configuration (like -Xmx, -Xms...).

Comment: Make sure to update your X.org and Mesa to the latest versions - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228866/optimizing-memory-leakage-in-javafx/40239829#40239829) - there was a bug which affected JavaFX on Linux which was recently fixed.

Comment: @sillyfly actually, I learned of the bug but couldn't find out how to update Ubuntu's Mesa for Intel graphics, so gave up..